# Old Android 1.6 app on new android emulator version

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager, avd-manager

I've just installed android-studio-ide-201.7199119-linux in order to use android emulator on linux. I've configured everything properly to work with android 8.1 image and all aps downloaded from play google store works fine with one exception.

This exception is Colleen https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.nick.jubanka.colleen - quite old application for Android 1.6. Interestingly on all mobile devices (real smartphones) I have  it works fine (8.1 and older versions of Android). However it doesn't work with AVD with android image 8.1. I also checked few other older image versions.

The reasons is that play store app displays the message that this app (=colleen) is not compatible with my device (=android emulator). It surprises me that with a real smartphone with Android 8.1 works fine but not with emulator. I've installed all updates, I deleted cache data of play store app and nothing helps. After some investigation I'm wondering if it might be the case that sdk for Colleen is very old (as I mentioned it's 1.6). I'm guessing that perhaps android emulator doesn't have old libraries for 1.6, while real smartphones still have. Any idea if it might be a reason or something else? How to correct it to make Colleen work on android emulator? I also tried installing Colleen directly from file, but installing failed.

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: It's probably not built for your CPU architecture.

Comment: @Vym, good point. I haven't though about that. Probably the only way to get my CPU version is to compile this from sources...